# Rotação de imagem não funciona corretamente no Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Estou tentando utilizar uma função em jQuery, e a mesma funciona bem no Firefox mas no Chrome ela simplesmente não inicia, fica parada na primeira imagem e não passa para as demais.

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz de **como faço para que funcione também no Chrome?**

Segue meu código `jQuery`:

```
var intervalId;
var slidetime = 3500; // milliseconds between automatic transitions

$(document).ready(function() {  

  // Comment out this line to disable auto-play
    intervalID = setInterval(cycleImage, slidetime);

    $(".main_image .desc").show(); // Show Banner
    $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0.85 }, 1 ); // Set Opacity

    // Click and Hover events for thumbnail list
    $(".image_thumb ul li:first").addClass('active'); 
    $(".image_thumb ul li").click(function(){ 
        // Set Variables
        var imgAlt = $(this).find('img').attr("alt"); //  Get Alt Tag of Image
        var imgTitle = $(this).find('a').attr("href"); // Get Main Image URL
        var imgDesc = $(this).find('.block').html();    //  Get HTML of block
        var imgDescHeight = $(".main_image").find('.block').height();   // Calculate height of block    

        if ($(this).is(".active")) {  // If it's already active, then...
            return false; // Don't click through
        } else {
            // Animate the Teaser               
            $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0, marginBottom: -imgDescHeight }, 250 , function() {
                $(".main_image .block").html(imgDesc).animate({ opacity: 0.85,  marginBottom: "0" }, 250 );
                $(".main_image img").attr({ src: imgTitle , alt: imgAlt});
            });
        }

        $(".image_thumb ul li").removeClass('active'); // Remove class of 'active' on all lists
        $(this).addClass('active');  // add class of 'active' on this list only
        return false;

    }) .hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('hover');
        }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('hover');
    });

    // Toggle Teaser
    $("a.collapse").click(function(){
        $(".main_image .block").slideToggle();
        $("a.collapse").toggleClass("show");
    });

    // Function to autoplay cycling of images
    // Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9259171/477958
    function cycleImage(){
    var onLastLi = $(".image_thumb ul li:last").hasClass("active");       
    var currentImage = $(".image_thumb ul li.active");


    if(onLastLi){
      var nextImage = $(".image_thumb ul li:first");
    } else {
      var nextImage = $(".image_thumb ul li.active").next();
    }

    $(currentImage).removeClass("active");
    $(nextImage).addClass("active");

        // Duplicate code for animation
        var imgAlt = $(nextImage).find('img').attr("alt");
        var imgTitle = $(nextImage).find('a').attr("href");
        var imgDesc = $(nextImage).find('.block').html();
        var imgDescHeight = $(".main_image").find('.block').height();

        $(".main_image .block").animate({ opacity: 0, marginBottom: -imgDescHeight }, 250 , function() {
      $(".main_image .block").html(imgDesc).animate({ opacity: 0.85,    marginBottom: "0" }, 250 );
      $(".main_image img").attr({ src: imgTitle , alt: imgAlt});
        });
  };

});// Close Function
```

Html:

```
<div id="main" class="container">
<div class="main_image">
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/img/load.gif" alt="- banner1" />
<div class="desc">
<div class="block">
</div>
</div>
    </div>

    <div class="image_thumb">
        <ul>
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
query_posts("posts_per_page=4&category_name=novidades&paged=$paged"); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>         
            <li>
<a href=" <?php
//Pega as imagens anexadas desse post
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'numberposts' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
        $img = wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID );
                break;
        }
}
echo $img; 
?>"></a>
<div class="block">
<h2><a target="_self" href="#" OnClick="javascript:window.document.location=('<?php the_permalink() ?>');" rel="bookmark" ><?php limit_title(28); ?></a></h2>
<small><?php ob_start(); the_excerpt(); echo dp_clean(ob_get_clean(), 110); ?> [...]</small>
</div>
 </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query();?>            
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Gustavo, seja bem vindo ao SOpt. Fiz uma pequena edição no seu post, então confere aí se ainda reflete sua intenção original. Caso queira, você pode também editar o post, ou mesmo reverter a edição. Inclusive, seria bom você editar a pergunta e incluir também o trecho do código HTML correspondente ao JQuery que está dando problema, pois isso aumenta bastante as chances de receber a resposta que procura.

Comment: Opa dicas bem vindas e ja atendidas!

Comment: Tente diminuir o código para deixar apenas a tópico da rotação da imagem em foco (tem até PHP numa questão de HTML/JavaScript). Isolar o problema vai ajudar as outras pessoas lerem o seu código, testar e encontrar o problema.

Comment: ta resolvido então @GustavoCastro ? poste a resposta ou faça suas considerações.

Answer (score 1):

sua resposta esta aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/68964/2/

e foi respondida no seu próprio código fonte ( esta em comentário ) da uma olhada ai no seu código a linha:

```
// Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9259171/477958
```

e segue esse link https://stackoverflow.com/a/9259171/477958 lá tem um código exemplo que testei aqui no chrome e resolveu

**Observação:** Quando há problemas de incompatibilidade entre navegadores geralmente é alguma propriedade do CSS que só existe em um determinado navegador ex:

```
.ui-button { -moz-user-select: none; } /* PARA QUE O TEXTO DO BOTAO NAO SEJA SELECIONADO COM O MOUSE*/
```